# SQLite -Refer a database to another database

Tags: android, database, sqlite

I have two SQLite databases in my android app.One stores data of signup members and second one stores the products added by members.Currently it shows all products selected by all members in that database.But I want to display products added only by the loggedin member at a time.How can I refer the logged in user and products he added only by him

**1st database :** shopping ; **its table :** contacts

**2nd database :** addcart  ; **its table :** add2cart

Comment: try using one sqlite database instead of two, this will make your life much easier.

Answer (score 0):

You can put everything under one database and simply put WHERE condition to select 
by user id